# Formatting a string containing operations and digits

Tags: java, android, regex, kotlin

I just want to format a string containing operations and digits.

For example:
`1035+56-7894*9985.3` to `1,035+56-7,894*9,985.3`

I just need to add a comma every 3 digits.
I want just to take care of numbers and ignore the operations and anything else that is not a number.

Comment: *I just need to add a comma every 3 digits* -- you probably don't want to do this actually. Formatting (decimal) numbers is locale dependent. You should just have a number and let the OS figure out how to display it. There are format specifiers for this. Also I downvoted your question because you have shown no effort or anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the numbers and keep everything else as is using Kotlins [`Regex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html) [`#replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/replace.html):

```
val input = "1035+56-7894*9985.3"

val numberRegex = Regex("[\\d,.]+") // this actually filters out consecutives digits, commas and dots 

val result = numberRegex.replace(input) { 
    val num = BigDecimal(it.value)
    "%,.2f".format(Locale.US, num)
}

println(result)
```

Which will print the following for your example:

```
1,035.00+56.00-7,894.00*9,985.30
```

Or if you really must retain the decimal places, use the following formatting instead:

```
"%,.${max(0, num.stripTrailingZeros().scale())}f".format(Locale.US, num)
```

which will print:

```
1,035+56-7,894*9,985.3
```

Comment: Please stop attacking my answer, thank you.  Both of our answers are sub optimal, because in production we wouldn't remotely be using a single regex to parse an arithmetic expression, we would be using some type of parser.  You're a Lexus, and I'm just a Toyota, but using a parser would be the Maserati.

Comment: I didn't want to attack your answer... I just wondered and I am always curious. Maybe there is something I didn't take into consideration... That's why I asked. Regarding the "operator targeting" that was just as I interpreted your code (it splits on the boundaries of the operators and checks the operators in the condition).

Comment: I upvoted you, your answer is better than mine.  It is preferable to just isolate the numbers, but I didn't think to use the regex API the way you have.

Comment: I spend _way_ too much time on this site, and it's easy to misread someone's intentions in comments, because we can't see the other person's actual emotions.

Comment: Did you try it? It should also format your example correctly. Note, that you may want a parser instead if there are more things to consider. The regex I used has the following flaws: doesn't catch negative sign, catches also one to many `,` and `.` or a combination thereof, which are surely no numbers, if the digits are missing. The regex could be improved to consider that too, however it isn't that readable then anymore.

Comment: On the other hand you didn't want to format the negative sign  specially, so that's ok. You could also just use a try/catch when parsing the value and skip the replacement (i.e. return the `it.value` directly) when it isn't parseable. Still that's not a real parser yet ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script which gets very close to your exact expected output:

```
String input = "1035+56-7894*9985.3";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=[+*/-])|(?=[+*/-])");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for (String part : parts) {
    if (!part.equals("+") && !part.equals("-") && !part.equals("*") && !part.equals("/")) {
        double num = Double.parseDouble(part);
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter(temp, Locale.US);
        formatter.format("%,.2f", num);
        sb.append(temp);
    }
    else {
        sb.append(part);
    }
}

System.out.println(sb);

1,035.00+56.00-7,894.00*9,985.30
```

### Demo

The secret sauce of this answer is to split your arithmetic string on the following pattern:

```
(?<=[+*/-])|(?=[+*/-])
```

This will split either before or after an operation symbol, while at the same time retaining those symbols as items in the resulting array.  This makes it easy for us to iterate the array of strings and then format the numbers, which keeping the symbols on tap for later when we need to rebuild the original arithmetic expression.

Then, for each number, we format it as a two decimal place number with a comma thousands separator.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you go for the operator when splitting instead of just filtering out the numbers? Note, that you can also "simplify" your `if` using `when` as follows: `when (part) { "+","-","*","/" -> sb.append(part); else -> { ... }`

Comment: @Roland Who says I'm going for the operator?  I am splitting at boundaries on either side of the operator.  But, you made me just realized I missed an edge case: negative numbers.  I'll wait for the OP to complain before I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The code below adds to "Tim Biegeleisen" solution by dynamically changing the number of digits after the decimal point when formatting the expression.

1) Demo.class:----------

```
public class Demo extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText edt;
private TextView tv;
private Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.demo);

    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String input = edt.getText().toString();
            if (!input.isEmpty()) {
                String[] parts = input.split("(?<=[+*/-])|(?=[+*/-])");
                for (String part : parts) {
                    if (!part.equals("+") && !part.equals("-") && !part.equals("*") && !part.equals("/")) {
                        double num = Double.parseDouble(part);
                        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
                        if (!isValidInteger(part)) { // if number is a decimal
                            int number_of_digits_after_decimal_point = 2;
                            try {
                                String[] part_split = part.split("\\."); // split number based on "."
                                if (part_split.length == 2) {
                                        number_of_digits_after_decimal_point = part_split[1].length(); // set number_of_digits_after_decimal_point to be equal to the
                                    // length of the string after the decimal point.
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Formatter formatter = new Formatter(temp, Locale.US);
                            formatter.format("%,." + number_of_digits_after_decimal_point + "f", num);
                            sb.append(temp);
                        } else { // if number is an integer
                            Formatter formatter = new Formatter(temp, Locale.US);
                            formatter.format("%,.0f", num);
                            sb.append(temp);
                        }
                    } else {
                        sb.append(part);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            tv.setText(sb.toString());
        }
    });
}

public static boolean isValidInteger(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            Integer val = Integer.valueOf(value);
            if (val != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

2) demo.xml:---------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/edt"
    android:hint="Input"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Output"
    android:id="@+id/tv"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Convert"
    android:id="@+id/b"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

3) Output:---------

[image: Output]

Comment: Nice catch with the locale. Otherwise, it uses the phone's locale, which means it doesn't result in that exact format if the locale isn't US.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, which is locale specific:

```
    String startString = "1035+56-7894*9985.3";
    String signs = startString.replaceAll("[^-+*/]", "") + " ";
    String[] numbers = startString
        .replaceAll(",", ".")
        .replaceAll("[-+*/]", " ")
        .split(" ");

    DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#");

    StringBuilder targetString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        targetString.append(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(numbers[i]))).append(signs, i, i + 1);
    }
    targetString = new StringBuilder(targetString.toString().trim());

    System.out.println(targetString);
```

prints:

```
1,035+56-7,894*9,985.3
```

or

```
1.035+56-7.894*9.985,3
```

depending on the locale settings.